# Angular ng-form with ng-repeat new form start as invalid

Tags: angularjs

I have view that contains list of people to add, each row represent a person, each row is an item in array of persons (people), I do repeat with ng-rpeat on this array, my issue when I add new row or load page the fileds start invalid even with `novalidate`, And any row have invalid input the fields become invalid.

The code :

HTML:

```
<ng-form name="pplForm" flex layout="row" layout-sm="column" layout-align="start center" ng-repeat="person in vm.company.People" ng-if="person.Status != 'deleted'">
                    <div layout="column" layout-align="start center" flex="20">
                        <md-input-container class="pb-0">
                            <label class="md-subhead">First Name</label>
                            <input required name="firstName" ng-model="person.FirstName">
                            <div ng-messages="editCompanyForm.firstName.$error">
                                <div ng-message="required">First Name is required.</div>
                            </div>
                        </md-input-container>
                    </div>
                    <div layout="column" layout-align="start center" flex="20">
                        <md-input-container class="pb-0">
                            <label class="md-subhead">Last Name</label>
                            <input required name="lastName" ng-model="person.LastName">
                            <div ng-messages="editCompanyForm.lastName.$error" >
                                <div ng-message="required">Last Name is required.</div>
                            </div>
                        </md-input-container>
                    </div>
                    <div layout="column" layout-align="start center" flex="20">
                        <md-input-container class="pb-0">
                            <label class="md-subhead">Phone Number</label>
                            <input name="phone" required ng-model="person.PhoneNumber" ng-pattern="/^([0-9]{3}) [0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$/">
                            <div ng-messages="editCompanyForm.phone.$error">
                                <div ng-message="pattern">(###) ###-#### - Please enter a valid phone number.</div>
                            </div>
                        </md-input-container>
                    </div>
                    <div layout="column" layout-align="start center" flex="20">
                        <md-input-container class="pb-0">
                            <label class="md-subhead">Email Address</label>
                            <input required minlength="10" maxlength="100" ng-pattern="/^.+@.+\..+$/" ng-model="person.Email" name="email">
                            <div ng-messages="editCompanyForm.email.$error">
                                <div ng-message-exp="['required', 'minlength', 'maxlength', 'pattern']">
                                    Invalid e-mail address.
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </md-input-container>
                    </div>

                    <div layout="column" layout-align="end start" flex="15">
                        <md-button class="md-icon-button md-warn" type="button"
                                   ng-click="vm.removePerson($index)" aria-label="Remove Person">
                            <md-icon md-font-icon="icon-minus-circle"></md-icon>
                        </md-button>
                    </div>

                </ng-form>
```

Code inside controller:

```
var vm = this;
vm.people = People; // its resolved and come from backend could be {} initially.

vm.addPerson = addPerson;
vm.removePerson = removePerson;

if (!vm.company.People || vm.company.People.length === 0) {
    addPerson();
}

function addPerson() {
    if (!vm.company.People) {
        vm.company.People = [];
    }
    vm.company.People.push({ Status : 'added'});
}

function removePerson(index) {
    if (getActivePersons().length > 1) {
        var person = vm.company.People[index];
        // If is new person no need to send it at all.
        if (person.Status && person.Status === 'added') {
            vm.company.People.splice(index, 1);
        } else { // If has status (or empty cuz is no action done before), then it need to be handeled from backend too.
            vm.company.People[index].Status = 'deleted';
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just added the names for fileds, and postfix it with `{{$index}}` and this solved the all problems that I was have:

```
<ng-form name="pplForm_{{$index}}" flex layout="row" layout-sm="column" layout-align="start center" ng-repeat="person in vm.company.People" ng-if="person.Status != 'deleted'">
                    <div layout="column" layout-align="start center" flex="20">
                        <md-input-container class="pb-0">
                            <label class="md-subhead">First Name</label>
                            <input required name="firstName_{{$index}}" ng-model="person.FirstName">
                            <div ng-messages="editCompanyForm.firstName.$error">
                                <div ng-message="required">First Name is required.</div>
                            </div>
                        </md-input-container>
                    </div>
                    <div layout="column" layout-align="start center" flex="20">
                        <md-input-container class="pb-0">
                            <label class="md-subhead">Last Name</label>
                            <input required name="lastName_{{$index}}" ng-model="person.LastName">
                            <div ng-messages="editCompanyForm.lastName.$error" >
                                <div ng-message="required">Last Name is required.</div>
                            </div>
                        </md-input-container>
                    </div>
                    <div layout="column" layout-align="start center" flex="20">
                        <md-input-container class="pb-0">
                            <label class="md-subhead">Phone Number</label>
                            <input name="phone_{{$index}}" required ng-model="person.PhoneNumber" ng-pattern="/^([0-9]{3}) [0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$/">
                            <div ng-messages="editCompanyForm.phone.$error">
                                <div ng-message="pattern">(###) ###-#### - Please enter a valid phone number.</div>
                            </div>
                        </md-input-container>
                    </div>
                    <div layout="column" layout-align="start center" flex="20">
                        <md-input-container class="pb-0">
                            <label class="md-subhead">Email Address</label>
                            <input required minlength="10" maxlength="100" ng-pattern="/^.+@.+\..+$/" ng-model="person.Email" name="email_{{$index}}">
                            <div ng-messages="editCompanyForm.email.$error">
                                <div ng-message-exp="['required', 'minlength', 'maxlength', 'pattern']">
                                    Invalid e-mail address.
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </md-input-container>
                    </div>

                    <div layout="column" layout-align="end start" flex="15">
                        <md-button class="md-icon-button md-warn" type="button"
                                   ng-click="vm.removePerson($index)" aria-label="Remove Person">
                            <md-icon md-font-icon="icon-minus-circle"></md-icon>
                        </md-button>
                    </div>

                </ng-form>
```